# Parse string to array with only start tag

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I have a TextArea with text in this format:

```
{verse1}
   [Am]Bla bla bla bla[B]
   ...
{verse2}
   ...
{verse3}
   ...
```

I need to parse id to array in pure Javascript. I don't know how to tackle this problem when I have only starting symbol.

Desired output is something like:

```
[
   {"verse1": "[Am]Bla bla bla bla[B]"},
   {"verse2": "..."},
   {"verse3": "..."}
]
```

P.S.: names between '{' ... '}' are user defined.

EDIT: real life example: http://pastebin.com/TpZmeP1Y

Comment: What "id" are you talking about? Show us your desired output.

Comment: added desired output... don't need to contain the names of parts

Comment: Instead of an array of objects with each having only one property, you could create *one* object where each "{verseX}" thingy is a property. That would only work if those names are unique though.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *"when I have only starting symbol"*?

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net with more real world text in textarea that shows also what your `{verse}` syntax will look like

Comment: It is not a web page. ... actual text inside TextArea looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/TpZmeP1Y

Comment: Do you want the multiple lines within one verse just as one big string? or should the lines be separate objects and if yes, what should the structure look like?

Comment: Multiple lines as one string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic way of doing it. You can see it in action <kbd>[here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLN6/)</kbd>. However, it splits by lines, so it assumes correct whitespaces and formatting etc. It's not the best or prettiest way this can be done – but it is a fully working example.

I generally don't both post a fully working version and code that is "perfect", because it's supposed to start you off and give you an idea rather than solve it completely.

```
var data = (function (input) {
    'use strict';

    var lines = input.split(/\n/),
        output = {},
        currentKey;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        if (line.match(/^\{\w+\}$/)) {
            currentKey = line.substr(1, line.length - 2);
            output[currentKey] = "";
        } else {
            output[currentKey] += line;
        }
    }

    return output;
})(document.getElementById('input').innerHTML);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: That is more than enough for me. I was stuck and upon seeing your code I had an eureka moment. Thank you!